# Redirecionamento de domínio

Tags: java, html, redirecionamento

Existe alguma forma de redirecionar o domínio para uma pasta no `public_html` ao invés de adicionar um arquivo `index.html` com redirecionamento automático?

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Use .htaccess.

Exemplo:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.novosite.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]`